# Notification Pop-up with with missing characters

Tags: release-loki, notifications

- Using fully updated Loki on a:
- Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz

A couple days ago notifications starting showing up with missing characters. 
This error happens across programs. The image is from a notification of Spotify, but the first time I notice was from a news update. Now I do not receive any complete notification. I have not installed any alien repository or new program in the last couple of days. But I do update Elementary every single day.

(Sorry for the poor quality of the attached img, it's taken with my mobile, the screen shots did not include the notifications pop up)[image: As you can see only a few characters show up]

Is this identified and can someone help me fix it?

Regards, 
Nuno

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now resolved.

All I did was update Loki.
(Unfortunately I do not have anything more specific than this)